# Perl : convert new line to comma delimited between 2 repeating words

Tags: regex, perl

Below is the output of of a single column with a repeating line that can be part of a regex/split etc.

I would like to convert the grouped column into a comma delimited format. Can someone help me with this?

Before:

```
An instance of HostInfo
1=?  
2=?   
3=?    
4=?  
5=?
An instance of HostInfo
1=?
2=?
3=?
4=?
5=?
```

After

```
1, 1=?, 2=?, 3=?, 4=?, 5=?

2, 1=?, 2=?, 3=?, 4=?, 5=?
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be remembered that *line* processing in Perl is an instance of *record* processing. And you can set the *record separator* to what fits your data.

Assuming the file *does* contain the string "An instance of HostInfo", you could do the following.

You can also set your record separator:

```
use English qw<$RS>;
my $old_rs = $RS;
local $RS = "An instance of HostInfo\n";
```

Then you can read the file in *those* chunks.

```
while ( <$input> ) { 
    chomp; # removes record separator
    next unless $_;
    ...
}
```

Then you can *split* the record into lines and rejoin them with commas. So the `...` is:

```
say join( ', ', split $old_rs );
```

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

undef $/;

my $output = <DATA>;

my @parts = split /An instance of HostInfo/m, $output;

my $ctr = 1;
for my $part (@parts) {
  my @lines = split "\n", $part;
  @lines = grep {$_} @lines;
  next unless @lines;
  s/^\s+//g for @lines;
  s/\s+$//g for @lines;
  print $ctr++, ', ', join(", ", @lines),"\n";
}

__DATA__
An instance of HostInfo
1=?  
2=?   
3=?    
4=?  
5=?
An instance of HostInfo
1=?
2=?
3=?
4=?
5=?
```

This reads your sample output into a single string, splits it on 'An instance of HostInfo',
then loops over each of those segments, splitting the lines, trimming them and finally joining them back together.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
use strict; use warnings;

my ($count, $hash);

# magic diamond operator to read INPUT
while (<>) {
    # removes newlines
    chomp;
    # if the line contains /An instance/
    # incrementing $count and skipping this line
    do{ $count++; next } if /An instance/;
    # else add current line in a reference to an array
    push @{ $hash->{$count} }, $_;
}

# iterating over "instances"
foreach my $first_level (sort keys %$hash) {
    # finally we print the result by de-referencing the HASH ref
    print "$first_level ", join ", ", @{ $hash->{$first_level} }, "\n";
}
```

**USAGE** :

```
perl script.pl < input_file.txt
```